# Brand New XPS 13 9320 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Overheating

Tags: dell, overheating, xps

It's been just two weeks now since I've received the new laptop. I noticed a few occasions where the laptop felt very hot. I use it for VS code for basic coding and bare minimum surfing of the web. Today I have been on Teams for a new job orientation. It got so hot that I had to shut it off and borrow my partner's computer. I couldn't find information on how to troubleshoot this issue or what could be causing it to overheat with just Teams going. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'd like to fix this before school begins this Fall where this will be my main computer for coding projects.

Edit: The laptop came with Ubuntu version 20.04 installed. I don't boot Windows on this computer as I didn't want a dual boot situation yet. I'll contact Dell after midterms and see if they ahe an answer. It hasn't been too much of an issue as of late.

Comment: Did it come with Ubuntu installed? if so, did you upgrade from version 20.04 or do a new install of 22.04? If not, do You still have Windows in it? Does it overheat when you boot Windows? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425093/edit) and add all these information.

Comment: I seem to remember that (some?) Dell laptops may have an option in their BIOS setup that allows you to choose between "active" and "passive" cooling. "Active" will use the fan, "passive" will merely try to regulate the temperature through throttling the processor's performance. I don't know whether the XPS family of laptops has this specific option or not, but I would definitely look around in the BIOS menu.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Dell?